# Enviar mais de um arquivo JSON em uma única requisição AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Estou fazendo a requisição de dois arquivos JSON pela função getJSON do JQuery. Estou tentando os enviar por meio de AJAX mas não estou conseguindo. 
Fiz o seguinte:

```
var data = '[{"agents": '+agents +', "projects":' + projects + ', "spaces": ' +spaces+', "events":' + events +'}]';
var data_json = JSON.parse(data);
```

Onde agents, projects, spaces e events foram recebidos por meio de getJSON.
O problema ocorre na chamada da função JSON.parse(). Como faço pra poder enviar todas as variaveis JSON em uma unica requisição?

Comment: Podes mostrar o conteúdo dessas variáveis?

Comment: E porque não `var data_json = [{agents: agents, projects: projects, spaces: spaces, events: events}];`? isso na verdade é só um objeto, nem precisava de ser array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se os dados vem do getJson eles não são strings;

```
var data = [{"agents":agents, "projects":projects, "spaces":spaces, "events": events}];
```

Deixa assim e envia normalmente pela requisição ajax.